# Python script writes twice in to the tables

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to automate this scenario. I have 2 .sql files (*add1.sql* and *add2.sql*) which has 1 insert script each.

My goal is to write one record to table1 by executing lines from *add1.sql* and one record to cm.cl by executing lines from *add2.sql*, waiting for about 5 mins so a backend service runs. This service writes from *DB1* to *DB2*. I then connect to DB2 to see if the record from *DB1* matches what was written to *DB2*. Depending no the results, an email is sent.

Below is my code. Everything works just fine except that it writes twice to *DB1*. So, basically 4 records are inserted instead of 2. Any idea why it writes 4 records?

```
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
import smtplib
sender = 'abc@abc.com'
receivers = ['abc@abc.com','xyz@abc.com']
import unittest
import time

class TestDB1(unittest.TestCase):


    def testing_master(self):

           Master_Conn = 'Driver=
 {SQLServer};Server=server\servername;Database=database;UID=userid;PWD=password'
           Master_db = pyodbc.connect(Master_Conn)
           Master_Cursor = Master_db.cursor()
           try:
               #Open, read and execute add_shell.sql
               file = open('C:\\aaa\\add1.sql', 'r')
               line = file.read()
               lines = line.replace('\n', ' ')
               file1 = open('C:\\aaa\\add2.sql', 'r')
               line1=file1.read()
               lines1=line1.replace('\n', ' ')
               Master_Cursor.execute(lines)
               time.sleep(1)
               Master_Cursor.execute(lines1)
               Master_db.commit()
               file.close()
               file1.close()

               #Get python object for latest record inserted in DB1
               Master_CID=Master_Cursor.execute("select col1 from tablename1 order by sequenceid desc").fetchone()
               #convert tuple to srting [0] gives first tuple element. 
               Master_CID_str=str(Master_CID[0])
               #Get GUID by stripping first 2 chars and last char.
               Master_CID_str=Master_CID_str[2:len(Master_CID_str)-1]
               Master_CLID=Master_Cursor.execute("select col2 from tablename2 order by sequenceid desc").fetchone()
               Master_CLID_str=str(Master_CLID[0])
               Master_CLID_str=Master_CLID_str[2:len(Master_CLID_str) - 1]



           # Wait for service that transfers data from one db to another DB to run
               time.sleep(310)
           finally:
                Master_Cursor.close()
                Master_db.close()

           return Master_CID,Master_CID_str,Master_CLID,Master_CLID_str


    def testing_int_instance(self):
           #unpacking return value of tuple from testing_master() function
           Master_CID,Master_CID_str,Master_CLID,Master_CLID_str=self.testing_master()
           print ("printing from testing_int_instance {0}".format(Master_CID))
           Int_Instance_Conn = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=server2\servername2;Database=database2;UID=uid;PWD=password;'
           Int_db = pyodbc.connect(Int_Instance_Conn)
           Int_Cursor = Int_db.cursor()
           #return Int_db, Int_Cursor
           #execute select from  db where col matches that of one inserted in master db.
           Int_Instance_CID=Int_Cursor.execute("select col1 from table1 where cartridgemodelid = '%s'" %(Master_CID_str)).fetchone()
           print(Int_Instance_CID)
           smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('22.101.1.333', 25)
           if (Master_CID==Int_Instance_CID):
               print("Matched")
               content="This email confirms successful  data transfer from Master to  Instance for col1: \n"
               message = "\r\n".join(["From:" + sender,"To:" + str(receivers[:]),"Subject: Test Result","",content +Master_CID_str])
               #smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('22.101.2.222', 25)
               smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
           elif (Master_CID!=Int_Instance_CID):
               print("no match")
               content = "This email confirms failure of  data transfer from DB1 to DB2 for COL1: \n"
               message = "\r\n".join(["From:" + sender, "To:" + str(receivers[:]), "Subject: Test Result", "",content +Master_CID_str])
               smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
           Int_Instance_CLID=Int_Cursor.execute("select COL2 from table2 where col= '%s'" %(Master_CLID_str)).fetchone()
           print (Int_Instance_CLID)
           if (Master_CLID == Int_Instance_CLID):
               print ("Printing int_instance CLID {0}".format(Int_Instance_CLID))
               content = "This email confirms successful data transfer from DB1 to DB2 for COL: \n"
               message = "\r\n".join(
                  ["From:" + sender, "To:" + str(receivers[:]), "Subject: Test Result", "", content + Master_CLID_str])
               #smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('22.101.2.222', 25)
               smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
               print ("Ids Matched")
           elif (Master_CLID != Int_Instance_CLID):
DB1 to DB2 for COL: \n"
               message = "\r\n".join(
                  ["From:" + sender, "To:" + str(receivers[:]), "Subject: Test Result", "", content + Master_CLID_str])
               #smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('22.101.2.222', 25)
               smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
           smtpObj.quit()


           Int_db.close()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    unittest.main()

add1.sql is:

```sql
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @PartNumber VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @Name='test'+convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
SELECT @PartNumber='17_00001_'+convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT @Id = NEWID()
SELECT @FileName = 'test.xml'
SELECT @XML='<model>
   <xml tags go here>
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1
         (ID,Name,Type,Desc,Number,Revision,Model,status,Modifiedby,Modifiedon)
   VALUES(@Id,@Name,'xyz','',@partnumber,'01',@XML,'A','453454-4545-4545-4543-345342343',GETUTCDATE())
```

add2.sql is:

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @CM_Name VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @PartNumber VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT @Id=NEWID()
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @CMId VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @CM_PartName VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @CM_Partnumber VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @Name='test'+convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
SELECT @PartNumber='test'+convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @FileName = 'test.xml' 
SELECT @CMId = CM.CMID,
    @CM_Name = CM.CMName,
    @CM_PN  = CM.PN
    FROM cm.Model CM
    WHERE CM.MName LIKE 'test%'
    ORDER BY CM.ModifiedBy DESC 
SELECT @XML='<Layout>
   other xml tags...

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cm.CL(ID, ModelID, Layout, Description, PN, Revision, CLayout, Status, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id, @CMId, @Name, '', @PartNumber, '01', @XML, 'A', '453454-345-4534-4534-4534543545', GETUTCDATE()
    FROM cm.table1 CM
    WHERE CM.Name=@CM_Name
    AND CM.Partnumber=@CM_Partnumber
```

Comment: First, the most important item: where do you call these functions? You only define them here. Please fix up the code at bottom of second method. Second no one writes to a database but tables. Which tables repeat the data of the two scripts? And finally, one of the scripts uses `[TABLENAME]`. What is that?

Comment: 3) Both tables (from both insert scripts) repeat data. Note: If I comment out time.sleep(310) in testing_master(self) function, it just writes one record each(from each insert script) into each table I am not sure why it writes twice (4 records in to 2 tables) with time.sleep(310). I need this to be there since I have to wait for the windows service to run
 I even tried putting time.sleep(310) out of first function but that did not work either. I cannot user teardown method to place time.sleep(310)  since I do not want it to run after each function.
4)Actual table name goes into [TABLENAME].

Comment: I forgot to paste the calling function. Below is what goes at the bottom of the second function. 
if name__=='__main':
  unittest.main()
2) I meant to say writes into 'table' and not 'database'

Comment: My original post has been updated.

Comment: Since it does write into the tables and sends out emails, I doubt if the issue is regarding functions being called incorrectly. 
Seems to me like time.sleep(310) is causing it to write twice. If I comment that line, my code just works fine but like I said I need that to be there to wait for the windows service to run.
If you are interested, below link gives details about unittest.main().
http://elbenshira.com/blog/behind-pythons-unittest-main/

Comment: Thanks, link was helpful. Also, what is the *backend Windows service*? How is it triggered? Automatically from a stored proc with every append? There may be an opportunity for Python to trigger it.

Comment: It is system service set to run every 5 minutes. This needs to be up and running always. I will not be able to have python trigger it.

Comment: It might be this *system service* causing the issue. What is it? A windows scheduled task? Is it proprietary, third-party API? Does it do other things? I'm also reading that it might even be *unittest*. How are you running this script? From command line terminal? Or an IDE like PyCharm? Try the terminal: `python Script.py`. Also, try removing all *unittest* and just call the defined functions on their own.

Comment: I am running my scripts from PyCharm. I tried running from command line terminal (scriptname.py) and saw the same behavior (writes twice).  I tried removing unittest and just called the defined functions and saw the same behavior (writes twice). I started running my script at 9:24. It writes '17_00001_09:24:58' in to the first table(expected). After about 5 mins (I am thinking this is the sleep), it again wrote '17_00001_09:30:38'  in to the same table (not expected)
Per DBA (who knows about the windows service running) it is not the service that is causing the writing twice.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you *are* calling `test_master()` twice! First as your named method and then in second method when you unpack the returned values. Below is a demonstration of defined methods outside of the *Class* object. If called as is, *testing_master* will run twice.

Consider also using a context manager to read .sql scripts using `with()` which handles open and close i/o operations shown below:

```
# FIRST CALL
def testing_master():
    #...SAME CODE...
    try:
        with open('C:\\aaa\\add1.sql', 'r') as file:
            lines = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')    
        Master_Cursor.execute(lines)
        Master_db.commit()

        time.sleep(1)

        with open('C:\\aaa\\add2.sql', 'r') as file1:
            lines1 = file1.read().replace('\n', ' ')    
        Master_Cursor.execute(lines1)
        Master_db.commit()

    #...SAME CODE...  
    return Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str


def testing_int_instance():
    # SECOND CALL
    Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str = testing_master()    
    #...SAME CODE...

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    testing_master()
    testing_int_instance()
```

Commenting out the `time(310)` seems like it works but as you mention the background Windows service does not effectively run and so interrupts database transfer.

To resolve, consider calling the second method at the end of the first by passing the values as parameters without any `return` and remove unpacking line. Then, in the main global environment, only run `testing_master()`. Of course qualify with `self` when inside a *Class* definition.

```
def testing_master():
    #...SAME CODE...
    testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str)

def testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str):
    #...SKIP UNPACK LINE 
    #...CONTINUE WITH SAME CODE...

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    testing_master()
```

Due to your `unittest`, consider slight adjustment to original setup where you qualify every variable with `self`:

```
def testing_master():
    ...
    self.Master_CID=Master_Cursor.execute("select col1 from tablename1 order by sequenceid desc").fetchone()
    self.Master_CID_str=str(Master_CID[0])
    self.Master_CID_str=Master_CID_str[2:len(Master_CID_str)-1]
    self.Master_CLID=Master_Cursor.execute("select col2 from tablename2 order by sequenceid desc").fetchone()
    self.Master_CLID_str=str(Master_CLID[0])
    self.Master_CLID_str=Master_CLID_str[2:len(Master_CLID_str) - 1]

def testing_int_instance(self):
    # NO UNPACK LINE
    # ADD self. TO EVERY Master_* VARIABLE
    ...
```

Comment: Ah. good catch. But with below code,I get NameError: name 'testing_int_instance' is not defined 
def testing_master():
     #...SAME CODE...
     testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str)

def testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str):
     #...SKIP UNPACK LINE 
     #...CONTINUE WITH SAME CODE...

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    testing_master()

Comment: Did you qualify it with `self.` if inside a Class as I mentioned in solution? In this answer no Class is used, only defined methods.

Comment: Yes. Below is my code.
class TestDB1(unittest.TestCase):
    def testing_master(self):
                connect to master
           global Master_db
           Master_db = pyodbc.connect(Master_Conn)
           Master_Cursor = Master_db.cursor()
           try:
                 ..
                 ..
    time.sleep(310)
           finally:
                Master_Cursor.close()
                       
    def testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str):
            ..
            ..
if __name__ == '__main__':
       testing_master()

Comment: I don't see where you call method: `self.testing_int_instance(...)` at end of *testing_master*. Also, add *self* as the first argument before params: `def testing_int_instance(self, Master_CID, ...)`.

Comment: with self.testing_int_instance(Master_CID, Master_CID_str, Master_CLID, Master_CLID_str) and
def testing_int_instance(self,Master_CID,Master_CID_str,Master_CLID,Master_CLID_str):, it writes once to each table- Yeah!!. Thanks so much.
However, as soon as I run the test, pycharm shows  error in testing_int_instance function. Spinner keeps going on for testing_master function. 
testMethod()
TypeError: testing_int_instance() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'Master_CID', 'Master_CID_str', 'Master_CLID', and 'Master_CLID_str'

Comment: Wonder why this error shows and why the 2nd function (testing_int_instance) runs first although testing_master is the first function in the class TestDB1

Comment: I do not use pycharm so cannot help in that regard. Something with that `unittest` possibly. You could go slightly back to your original setup with two functions but do not use a `return` or the unpacking line but qualify all *Master_* variables with `self.` See extended updated answer.